# Serializing null in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

When serializing arbitrary data via JSON.NET, any property that is null is written to the JSON as

> "propertyName" : null

This is correct, of course.

However I have a requirement to automatically translate all nulls into the default empty value, e.g. null `string`s should become `String.Empty`, null `int?`s should become `0`, null `bool?`s should be `false`, and so on.

`NullValueHandling` is not helpful, since I dont want to `Ignore` nulls, but neither do I want to `Include` them (Hmm, new feature?).

So I turned to implementing a custom `JsonConverter`.
While the implementation itself was a breeze, unfortunately this still didnt work - `CanConvert()` is never called for a property that has a null value, and therefore `WriteJson()` is not called either. Apparently nulls are automatically serialized directly into `null`, without the custom pipeline.

For example, here is a sample of a custom converter for null strings:

```
public class StringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    ...
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, 
                object value, 
                JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;

        if (strValue == null)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(String.Empty);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue(strValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Stepping through this in the debugger, I noted that neither of these methods are called for properties that have a null value.

Delving into JSON.NET's sourcecode, I found that (apparently, I didnt go into a lot of depth) there is a special case checking for nulls, and explictly calling `.WriteNull()`.

For what it's worth, I did try implementing a custom `JsonTextWriter` and overriding the default `.WriteNull()` implementation...

```
public class NullJsonWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    ... 
    public override void WriteNull()
    {
        this.WriteValue(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

However, this can't work well, since the `WriteNull()` method knows nothing about the underlying datatype. So sure, I can output `""` for any null, but that doesnt work well for e.g. int, bool, etc.

So, my question - short of converting the entire data structure manually, is there any solution or workaround for this?

Comment: I'm guessing the `WriteNull()` method is called internally within the JSON serialization process and you can't determine which value you are currently serializing?

Comment: The WriteNull method is called by the JsonSerializer when the property has a null value. To be accurate, the value I'm serializing is always null :), but yes there seems to be no way to know the underlying data type for which the null is being written.

Comment: What's the point of using nullable types if you are just going to ignore null as a valid state of the object?

Comment: @32bitkid good question, but in this case the nullable types are used server side (e.g. in the model), but the client/receiving end/view does not handle the null state very well (yes, I would rather have the client fixed, but its a complicated situation). In any event, just because I start with nullable types, shouldnt mean it cant be serialized into something else...

Comment: Is it possible to override any of the WriteValue(Nullable<T>) for your case where you want the default value for that type? Is the corresponding method called such as for a int? is WriteValue(Nullable<int>) called or does it directly flow to WriteNull()? 
[JsonTextWriter](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm)

Comment: After cursory look at the source code of Json.Net, I don't think you can do this easily without modifying its source code.

Comment: @ShelbyZ `if(value==null)` is pretty much the first case :(

Comment: Gosh I wish there was a way to serialize NULL when a JsonConverterAttribute has been specified on a property. I specifically need to modify output something other than "null" on nullable properties in my case too. Perhaps we can get a feature request going for this.

Comment: http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/22508

Comment: Omg TEN YEARS later.... ! And now there is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#handle-null-values `JsonConverter<T>.HandleNull` now enables a custom converter to handle null... ‍♀️

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Okay, I think I've come up with a solution (my first solution wasn't right at all, but then again I was on the train). You need to create a special contract resolver and a custom ValueProvider for Nullable types. Consider this:

```
public class NullableValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    private readonly object _defaultValue;
    private readonly IValueProvider _underlyingValueProvider;


    public NullableValueProvider(MemberInfo memberInfo, Type underlyingType)
    {
        _underlyingValueProvider = new DynamicValueProvider(memberInfo);
        _defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(underlyingType);
    }

    public void SetValue(object target, object value)
    {
        _underlyingValueProvider.SetValue(target, value);
    }

    public object GetValue(object target)
    {
        return _underlyingValueProvider.GetValue(target) ?? _defaultValue;
    }
}

public class SpecialContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IValueProvider CreateMemberValueProvider(MemberInfo member)
    {
        if(member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
        {
            var pi = (PropertyInfo) member;
            if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType && pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Nullable<>))
            {
                return new NullableValueProvider(member, pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First());
            }
        }
        else if(member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
        {
            var fi = (FieldInfo) member;
            if(fi.FieldType.IsGenericType && fi.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
                return new NullableValueProvider(member, fi.FieldType.GetGenericArguments().First());
        }

        return base.CreateMemberValueProvider(member);
    }
}
```

Then I tested it using:

```
class Foo
{
    public int? Int { get; set; }
    public bool? Boolean { get; set; }
    public int? IntField;
}
```

And the following case:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new SpecialContractResolver() };

        Assert.AreEqual(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, Formatting.None, settings), 
            "{\"IntField\":0,\"Int\":0,\"Boolean\":false}");
    }
}
```

Hopefully this helps a bit...

*Edit – Better identification of the a `Nullable<>` type*

*Edit – Added support for fields as well as properties, also piggy-backing on top of the normal `DynamicValueProvider` to do most of the work, with updated test*

Comment: I believe you can do Type.IsValueType if you want.

Comment: @IanJacobs I figured it out by using `GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Nullable<>)`.

Comment: Wow, this is... a bit more complicated than I expected. Especially for something so trivial... Anyway it will take me a while to plug this in and check, but it looks good! Thanks, in the meantime...

Comment: Will also need to put in a special case for String, since it's not actually a Nullable<> type...

Comment: @AviD Whoops, I forgot that you also needed to translate strings. But it would be implemented more or less the same way. You could create a new ValueProvider just for strings, or change the existing signature rather than passing in the generic type, just pass in the default value (and move the `Activator.CreateInstance()` up one level)

Comment: @AviD and I agree, it wasn't as intuitive as I thought it would be, but that was the only solution I could come up with that fits within the existing architecture of JSON.NET and doesn't require any changes to the library itself.

Comment: Yeah, from there its pretty simple to stretch to cover strings, I would just add another condition in there, pretty much in the same pattern. And hey, I'm not complaining about the complicated, just surprised... Thanks for this!

Comment: Excellent, this worked brilliantly! I did make a few small changes, such as pulling out the generic parameter inside the valueprovider, and setting the default only on demand, but overall your solution with IValueProvider did the trick! Thanks a ton!

Comment: I know we don't do this here but, after a neverending day : Thank you !

Comment: Omg TEN YEARS later.... ! And now there is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#handle-null-values `JsonConverter<T>.HandleNull` now enables a custom converter to handle null... ‍♀️