# WebApi jsonFormatter how to change Null String values to Empty String

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, jsonserializer

Im receiving quirky issues with my json data from my asp.net MVC WebApi coming into my kendoUI  controls because null strings are being sent across as

```
"FielName":null
```

Im wondering how do I go about setting up the jsonformatter on my webapi so that string fields with a null value return empty string "" instead of Null like? So looks like.

```
"FieldName":""
```

Thanks

Comment: This is answered in this previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-it-is-null-using-json-net

Comment: @PaigeCook That post seems to talk about ignoring null properties. I dont want to ignore them, I want to convert properties of type System.String to "" if they are null??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look to modify the JsonFormatter and change it's `ContractResolver` to be something a little different. This question: [Serializing null in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833961/serializing-null-in-json-net) looks like it could be easily adapted for your purposes (just by updating the default JsonFormatter).