# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject - Handling Empty Strings

Tags: serialization, compact-framework, json.net, deserialization

I am using Json.NET to serialize an object to be sent to a **compact framework 3.5 device** (lucky me).

My class on the compact device is:

```
public class Specification
{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Instructions { get; set; }
}
```

The Json being returned sent to the device is (notice the null for instructions):

```
string json = @"{""Name"":""Test"",""Instructions"":null,""Id"":""093a886b-8ed4-48f0-abac-013f917cfd6a""}";
```

...and the method being used to deserialize the json is...

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Specification>(json);
```

On the server I'm using the following to create the Json:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Formatting = Formatting.None;
serializer.Serialize(context.HttpContext.Response.Output, this.Data);
```

The problem is that on the compact framework, it's failing to put a value into result.Instructions which is causing a null reference when it is referenced later in the code.

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.Compact v3.5.0.0 (I think that's the latest version), and on the server I'm using Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.0.0.

**Question**

How can I either:

a) Change the server code to stick a "" instead of a null value in where a string is null.

or

b) Change the compact framework code to be able to handle null value strings.

**Things I've tried**

I've been looking through the documentation/examples of Json.Net and have tried a multitude of things like a implementing a `DefaultContractResolver`, and a custom `JsonContract`.  Maybe the answer lies within those but my lack of understanding of Json.Net at this level isn't helping!!

**Further info**

I was using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer for the server side serialisation, which did generated quotes in the event of empty strings.  Unfortunately, I need more flexibility with the serialization which is why I've started using Json.Net.

Any hints/tips appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - no answers, but having search all yesterday afternoon I went to bed, and search again this morning to find: [Serializing null in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8835237/192999), which pretty much answers my question.