# When using record types to deserialize JSON, how can I avoid null values for missing members?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am using Newtonsoft Json to deserialize JSON into C# record types. I'll provide examples below, but the theme of the challenge here is trying to get the object footprint and semantics in code that I like, while also getting the deserialization behavior I want. Essentially, I like to avoid `null` values inside deserialization code as much as possible. Mainly this applies to `string` and collection types: If a string property is missing, I don't want `null`, I want `""`. Similarly, for collection properties that are missing, I do not want `null` but an empty container (e.g. `Array.Empty<MyComplexType>()`).

The way I used to avoid this before `record` types is to explicitly specify property defaults, like this:

```cs
public class ReleaseProfileData
{
    IReadOnlyCollection<TermData> Required { get; set; } = Array.Empty<TermData>();
}
```

I cannot do this when I convert it to the short-form record type equivalent:

```cs
public record ReleaseProfileData(
    IReadOnlyCollection<TermData> Required = Array.Empty<TermData>()
);
```

So I resorted to this instead:

```cs
public record ReleaseProfileData(
    IReadOnlyCollection<TermData> Required
);
```

However, if in my JSON data I'm missing the `"required": []` property, the `Required` parameter here will be `null`. I instead want it to be an empty container.

I've considered two objects and doing a conversion between, but this feels overkill. I also looked into settings in NewtonsoftJson, such as `MissingMemberHandling`, `NullValueHandling`, etc. But none of these seem to simply say, "If a property is missing, give me an empty string or container instead of `null`".

I realize I can do a long-form version of my `record` type using `init` properties, but again this starts to get really verbose: Initialization is now done via brace-init style, instead of constructor. I can add a constructor, but again this makes it more verbose. And in addition to that I now need to implement `Destruction` methods if I want to break out my object into `var (first, second, etc)`. It just keeps getting worse.

What is a good approach here?

Comment: I didn't got your point exactly, but maybe this is what you want https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm

Comment: You might clarify your question a bit.  The questions [Json Convert empty string instead of null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23830206), [Overriding a property value in custom JSON.net contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46978914) and [How to default a null JSON property to an empty array during serialization with a List<T> property in JSON.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25148172) have already been asked and answered.  The general approach is to use a custom contract resolver to inject a custom value provider or default value.  Are those not working for you?

Comment: Also, do you want to set default null values only for missing values?  What should happen if the JSON explicitly contains a null value?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the a sample of your ideal `record` data model containing string and collection properties?

Comment: @dbc I'm not going to provide an example. I have only so much free time. I decided to spend that time making my question as detailed as I was able. If I wanted explicitly null values, I would have made the type `IReadOnlyCollection<TermData>?`. But that is not what I did. I would expect `null` to result in an exception being thrown. But that behavior is out of scope. Let's keep responses focused on the use case I mentioned in my question: Absence of the respective property from the source JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own property with the same name to "change" the generated positional property of the record. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#positional-syntax-for-property-definition):

> If the generated auto-implemented property definition isn't what you want, you can define your own property of the same name. For example, you may want to change accessibility or mutability, or provide an implementation for either the `get` or `set` accessor. If you declare the property in your source, you must initialize it from the positional parameter of the record. If your property is an auto-implemented property, you must initialize the property.

```cs
public record ReleaseProfileData(IReadOnlyCollection<object> Required)
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<object> Required { get; init; } = Required ?? Array.Empty<object>();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that null-coalescing operation executes at the wrong time to do anything useful, you'd get the same result from `= Array.Empty<object>()`

Comment: @BenVoigt when deserializing empty body (missing property) - yes, but for other cases - [no](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RHCSG8). Next sentence from documentation quote - _"If you declare the property in your source, you must initialize it from the positional parameter of the record"_

Comment: Oh I missed that this is using the new `record` keyword and `Required` is actually both the property name and also the constructor argument name.  Would be much more readable if the name collision were corrected, having the identifier `Required` find two different meanings in the same line of code is terrible style.

Comment: @BenVoigt it is not a name collision though. If any of the two will be changed you will end up with two properties.

Comment: I'd argue that the syntax should have been `public IReadOnlyCollection<object> Required { get; init; } = value ?? Array.Empty<object>();` since the `value` keyword already has meaning inside a property setter, and refers to the value passed in from outside.  Guess it's too late now though.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, possibly it would be a better alternative.

Comment: I did try this one too, but I honestly found the behavior confusing. If I left out the `Required ??` part, I wasn't sure what it meant to have "two properties with the same name", or so it appears at face value... Despite my confusion with the syntax, it seems like this is probably the closest I'm going to get to the best of both worlds.

Comment: I did discover this approach gets more confusing with nullable reference types. For example, Resharper says that the `?? Array.Empty()` part is superfluous unless I make the constructor parameter `IReadOnlyCollection<object>? Required`, but if I do *that*, then that affects the final type of the property, not the explicitly defined property (so code outside of the record thinks this type is nullable when it shouldn't be semantically).

Comment: @void.pointer `Required ??` is required cause in this context `Required` refers to the positional property of the record i.e. `ReleaseProfileData(... Required)` which will be used in the ctor. As for nullability the issue here is not the difference between classes and records but difference between the actual model and incoming model - i.e. it is possible that this property is null in json and the actual model does not reflect this.

Comment: Ideally, if the property is missing or null in JSON, I get an empty array. That's why I want the constructor to consume a nullable container (because it may be null coming from JSON) but the public property will not be nullable. Semantically I do not want to deal with nulls in my business logic. Empty array results in cleaner code due to less corner cases to code conditionals for.

Comment: Looks like the automatic `Deconstruct` method that gets implemented for the record type uses the types specified in the short-form/constructor, not the property itself. That's unfortunate. Because I need the parameter to be nullable, but the version used in code to be non-nullable.